# Laravel 5.2: Download PDF throws exception 'LogicException' with message 'The content cannot be set on a BinaryFileResponse instance.'

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5

I use below code to download the PDF files with the size of 4mb. The problem is that this works fine locally, but on my server it's not working. the download part isn't.

```
$pathToFile = public_path('attachments/products/pdf/xxx.pdf');
$headers = [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'];
return response()->download($pathToFile, 'xyz.pdf', $headers);
```